# AJAX form doesn't submit anymore after 1 error, should go to the next error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a AJAX form but i doesn't go to the next error when i submit. If i fill in gender and i click on submit it doesn't go to the next mandetory field error that needs to be filled in.

```
//submit account and password register second part (account)
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#register_second_part").on("submit", function(e){
  console.log("TEST1");
     e.preventDefault();
     var token = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
     var gender = $(".gender:checked").val();
     var firstname = $('#name').val();
     var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
     var country = $(".countrySelect").find("option:selected").text();
     var streetname = $('#streetname').val();
     var streetnumber = $('#streetnumber').val();
     var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();
     var city = $('#city').val();
     var date = $('#date').val();
     var phone = $('#phone').val();
     var email = $('#second-email').val();
    var password = $('#passwordForRegistration').val();

     $.ajax({
       url: "register_account_and_password_ajax.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { email: email,new_password: password,gender:gender,name:firstname,lastname:lastname,country:country,
              streetname:streetname,streetnumber:streetnumber,zipcode:zipcode,city:city,date:date,phone:phone,recaptcha:token},
              dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {

         if(data.type == 'success') {
             console.log("TEST2");
           $('#registerSpamMessage').modal();
           $('#registerSpamMessage').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
             $('#submitAccountRegister').html(
        "<span class='spinner-border spinner-border-sm' role='status' aria-hidden='true'></span> Laden..."
          );
             window.location='products.php';
          });
         } else if(data.type == 'error') {
             console.log("TEST3");
           $("#message2").html("<div class='alert alert-danger resizeFont' style='text-align:center;'>"+data.text+"</div>");
           // grecaptcha.reset();
           $(window).scrollTop(0);
         }
       }
     });

   });
 });
```

The button is like this:

```
<button id="submitAccountRegister" type="submit">Click</button>
```

I don't understand how it doesn't go to the next required field that needs to be filled in. It stops submitting after the first error.

```
    //See if gender is chosen
                            if (!isset($_POST['gender']))  {
                                array_push($errors, "");
                                $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "Choose your gender please"));
                                die($output);
                            }

                            //see if country is chosen
                            if($_POST["country"] == 'Select Country'){
                                array_push($errors, "");
                                $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "Choose your country please"));
                                die($output);
                            }

                            if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['streetname']) || empty($_POST['streetnumber'])
                                    || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($email) ||
                                    empty($_POST['new_password'])) {
                                        array_push($errors, "");
                                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "All fields are required to fill in except your Birth date, Zip code or phone number"));
                                        die($output);
                            }

                            if ( strlen($_POST['name']) > 80 || strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 80 || strlen($_POST['streetname']) > 80 || strlen($_POST['city']) > 80 ||
                                     strlen($_POST['new_password'] ) > 80) {
                                        array_push($errors, "");
                                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "For fields: Firstname, Lastname, Streetname, City and Password are a max of 80 characters allowed"));
                                        die($output);
                                    }

                                    if(strlen($_POST['streetnumber']) > 15) {
                                        array_push($errors, "");
                                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "For field Streetnumber is a max of 15 characters allowed"));
                                        die($output);
                                    }


                                    if(strlen($email) > 250) {
                                        array_push($errors, "");
                                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "For field Email is a max of 250 characters allowed"));
                                        die($output);
                                    }

                                    if($_POST['date'] && strlen($_POST['date']) > 10) {
                                        array_push($errors, "");
                                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "For field Birthdate is a max of 10 characters allowed"));
                                        die($output);
                                    }
```

A part of the PHP code is written like this.

Am i doing something wrong here? I hope someone can explain and help me. It's like it's frozen after the first error pops up.

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you mean by *"doesn't go to the next error when i submit"*?  Are you referring to an operation in the client-side code or in the server-side code?  Which specific operation in the code shown are you trying to indicate, and what specific result are you observing vs. what you are expecting?  If you're referring to the server-side code and asking why, after entering the `if (!isset($_POST['gender']))` block the code doesn't proceed to the next `if` block, it would be because you called `die()` which ends execution of the script.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Server side code is what i mean with next error @David

Comment: It sounds like that’s the problem then.  The script is terminating because you’re terminating the script.  Don’t call “die()” if you don’t want to end the script.  Instead, build up the response object in each “if” block and end the script at the end.